# Angularjs: convert standart select to ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have this select in angularjs that works perfect with my Web Service, but it have so many data, so I need a select searchable. I found the ui-select, and I am trying to convert this code (HTML and app.js) to ui-select:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="fabricante" data-ng-model="equipamento.RazaoSocial" ng-disabled="viewMode">
<option ng-repeat="fabricante in fabricantes" value="{{fabricante.RazaoSocial}}">{{fabricante.RazaoSocial}}</option></select>
```

App.js

```
// select fabricantes
$scope.fabricantes = [];
$scope.fabricante;// = null;
$scope.fabricantes = gettbfabricante();
gettbfabricante();
function gettbfabricante() {
    EmpApi.gettbfabricante().success(function (response) {
        $scope.fabricantes = response;
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.status = 'Não foi possível carregar os dados: ' + error.message;
        $window.alert($scope.status);
    });
};
```

Service.js

```
//get tbfabricante 
EmpApi.gettbfabricante = function () {
    return $http.get(urlBase + '/tbfabricante')
}
```

Can anyone help please? 
I tried to use this [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PKD6cLrbjc1kO8ypD7bK?p=preview).

Comment: post the json response of fabricants

Comment: did you tried ?

Comment: Json: 
`[{"TBEquipamento":[],"idFabricante":1,"RazaoSocial":"COMTRAFO","CNPJ":null,"Endereco":null,"Numero":null,"Complemento":null,"Bairro":null,"Cidade":null,"Estado":null,"CEP":null,"Telefone":null},{"TBEquipamento":[],"idFabricante":2,"RazaoSocial":"ABB","CNPJ":"","Endereco":"","Numero":0,"Complemento":"","Bairro":"","Cidade":"","Estado":"","CEP":"","Telefone":""},{"TBEquipamento":[],"idFabricante":3,"RazaoSocial":"ADELCO","CNPJ":"","Endereco":"","Numero":0,"Complemento":"","Bairro":"","Cidade":"","Estado":"","CEP":"","Telefone":""}]`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install ui-select using npm or bower
for npm run `npm install ui-select` and for bower run `bower install angular-ui-select`

after that in your html write :

```
 <ui-select ng-model="equipamento.RazaoSocial" ng-disabled ="viewMode">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one...">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="data in fabricantes | filter: $select.search track by data.RazaoSocial">
        {{fabricante.RazaoSocial}}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>'
```

Hope this will help you . If you want to learn or add more components in your ui-select refer this url [Ui-select documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select)

Comment: Almost! It gave this error: 

` "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: data in $select.items track by data.RazaoSocial, Duplicate key: Fockink, Duplicate value: {"TBEquipamento":[],"idFabricante":262,"RazaoSocial":"Fockink","CNPJ":"","Endereco":"","Numero":0,"Complemento":"","Bairro":"","Cidade":"","Estado":"","CEP":"","Telefone":""} `

Comment: I modify your html:

`    <ui-select ng-model="equipamento.RazaoSocial">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one..." >{{$select.selected.RazaoSocial}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="fabricante in fabricantes | filter: $select.search ">
            {{fabricante.RazaoSocial}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
    <p>ng-model: {{equipamento.RazaoSocial}}</p>
    <p>Selected: {{$select.selected.RazaoSocial}}</p>`


But it isn't passing the value, if a select a value in the select, nothing appear in ' Selected ng-model:'  Neither in 'Selected:'.